# addToBackStack displays all fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using MainActivity to manage the display of several fragments. I have a showFragment method that iterates through my fragment array and either shows/hides them, and sets the backstack accordingly. The issue is that any time I press the back button, the HomeFrag gets displayed, with all of the other fragments piled up underneath. I was under the impression from the documentation that the back button will reverse the last transaction (anything that was added before the commit). Can anyone explain why this might be causing this unexpected behavior? Here is my main activity. The fragments are all defined in activity_main.xml:

```
    public class MainActivity extends MenuBaseActivity {
    private static final int HOME = 0;
    private static final int WRITE = 1;
    private static final int UPLOAD = 2;
    private static final int SHARE = 3;
    private static final int SNAP = 4;
    private static final int POSITION = 5;

    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = POSITION + 1;

    /** The current fragment being displayed **/
    private int mCurrentFragment = -1;

    private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        fragments[HOME] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.homeFrag);
        fragments[WRITE] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.writeFrag);
        fragments[UPLOAD] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.uploadFrag);
        fragments[SHARE] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.shareFrag);
        fragments[SNAP] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.snapFrag);
        fragments[POSITION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.positionFrag);

        // If no fragments are currently being displayed, show the home frag
        if(mCurrentFragment == -1) {
            showFragment(0,true);
        }


    }

    /*
     * Handles the click event for all navigation buttons (navOnClick) in the fragments.
     */
    //TODO: Tag navigation with text strings instead of integers
    public void navOnClick(View v) {

        Object objectTag = v.getTag();
        int tag = Integer.valueOf(objectTag.toString());
        showFragment(tag, true);
    }


    public void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {

        Log.v(Constants.getLogTag(), "Main: fragmentIndex:" + fragmentIndex + " backstack:" + addToBackStack);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        //ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            if (i == fragmentIndex) {
                ft.show(fragments[i]);
              } else {
                ft.hide(fragments[i]);
            }
        }

        if (addToBackStack) {
            Log.v(Constants.getLogTag(), "Main: Adding to backstack");
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
        }

        //Update the current fragment identifier
        mCurrentFragment = fragmentIndex;

        ft.commit();
    }


}
```

Comment: You are iterating through your array and hiding every single fragment in one transaction, so when you hit the backbutton, it unhides all of them at once.

Comment: It seems messy in there. Change your whole logic, don't do thing like that.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh Maybe you could suggest a quick refactor, I don't think you're comment is very helpful as is.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to keep track of all of the fragments in an array?

Comment: @btse yes thats what I am saying, Why keep reference to all of the fragments? If you are trying to write an app in just one screen where you show and hide your GUI elements all the time then clearly its not a good design. E.g. One activity is keeping track of HOME, WRITE, UPLOAD, SHARE and what not and keep showing and hiding GUI depending on these operations then this is bad.

Comment: @btse - Not really, I pulled this example off of a tutorial, and I have actually found it at bit confusing.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh - So do you think it would make more sense to have a separate Activity for each fragment?

Comment: It all depends on your flow of app and business logic. E.g. At first glance this comes to my mind. User launches app home fragment is shown so put it in separate activity. User clicks snap button and snap fragment is shown, put it in separate activity too. Upload fragments seems to show progress so it can be used as DialogFragment any where no need for separate activity. As far as I can understand   each remaining fragment must go in separate activity **Or**

Comment: You can have a simple FrameActivity that contains simple empty full screen `FramLayout` then just keep instantiating and calling `replace` in conjunction with `addToBackStack` in just one `Activity`. But initiating all of them at once although only one is shown at a time is bad. Even `ViewPager` only initializes 3 `Fragment`s in total by default.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh - Thanks, that's helpful. One more question, do I really even need fragments? This app is pretty linear, and will be locked down on a handset layout (for now). I was just experimenting with fragments for any future modifications that may require them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34650/discussion-between-jwburnside-and-m-wajeeh)

Comment: @jwburnside I will answer that, and say no. If you intend on pretty much having each fragment be its own screen, then using a separate activity for each fragment that you are currently using is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I haven't tested this out personally, but let me know how this works.**

**I actually decided to keep the array so that we can properly hide each fragment when the activity is first started. I changed just a few small things that should fix your problem. There is no need to hide each fragment every time in a loop. You should only have to hide the current fragment each time.**

```
public class MainActivity extends MenuBaseActivity {
    private static final int HOME = 0;
    private static final int WRITE = 1;
    private static final int UPLOAD = 2;
    private static final int SHARE = 3;
    private static final int SNAP = 4;
    private static final int POSITION = 5;

    /** The current fragment being displayed **/
    private int mCurrentFragment = HOME;

    private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        fragments[HOME] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.homeFrag);
        fragments[WRITE] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.writeFrag);
        fragments[UPLOAD] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.uploadFrag);
        fragments[SHARE] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.shareFrag);
        fragments[SNAP] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.snapFrag);
        fragments[POSITION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.positionFrag);

        // Hide all of the fragments except for the home fragment
        for (int i = WRITE; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            ft.hide(fragments[i]);
        }

        ft.commit();
    }

    /*
     * Handles the click event for all navigation buttons (navOnClick) in the fragments.
     */
    //TODO: Tag navigation with text strings instead of integers
    public void navOnClick(View v) {

        Object objectTag = v.getTag();
        int tag = Integer.valueOf(objectTag.toString());
        showFragment(tag, true);
    }


    public void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {

        Log.v(Constants.getLogTag(), "Main: fragmentIndex:" + fragmentIndex + " backstack:" + addToBackStack);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        // I changed this part too. You will probably want to implement it this way
        // if you want to also see an animation when hitting the back button. I will
        // leave it up to you as an exercise to figure out how the other animator
        // files should be constructed
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_right, R.animator.slide_out_left, 
                               R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_out_right); 

        ft.hide(fragments[mCurrentFragment]);
        ft.show(fragments[fragmentIndex]);

        if (addToBackStack) {
            Log.v(Constants.getLogTag(), "Main: Adding to backstack");
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
        }

        //Update the current fragment identifier
        mCurrentFragment = fragmentIndex;

        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. While your example does work for the most part, I'm expecting to run into some headaches since I'm also using some built-in camera activities and 3rd party libraries. Plus fragments seem like overkill. Going to convert everything to an activity and only use fragments if I need a layout change for other devices.

Comment: @jwburnside That sounds good to me. Just as a side note, I think that the initial layout of your application was odd. If you were planning on using each fragment as its own screen, you should be treating each fragment essentially as an activity and creating them all programatically, i.e. create a separate Fragment class for each fragment. Hardcoding them all in xml and then hiding them all is an odd way to go about things and it prevents you from destroying the fragments if need be. Just something to keep in mind in the future.